# Instance variables scope in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, variables, scope, instance

I suppose the default scope for ivars is @protected.

I declared a variable like this in the header file of a class:

```
{
int _test1;
}
```

But I could print this variable _test1 using NSLog in a totally unrelated object.

```
NSLog(@"%d", _test1);
```

Why is _test1 available to the second object?

Where can I find the latest ivars scope rules?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the code where this happens.

Comment: If by "totally unrelated object" you mean an object of a different class and that the variable is not declared in a common superclass, then you're all wet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking objective-c v1, then you are correct... unless otherwise defined (by using the @public, @private, or @packaged keywords), ivars will default to @protected.

You're not showing your code, so I can't be certain, but I wonder if you have the same "issue" as described in this other post: [Objective-C - Private vs Protected vs Public](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869935/objective-c-private-vs-protected-vs-public)

For objective-c 2 this is kind of "deprecated". This article pretty much describes how to do this now: http://robsprogramknowledge.blogspot.com/2011/08/objective-c-property.html

The best place to go for the latest objective-c documentation is probably developer.apple.com... Here's a link to the latest programming manual: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html